# laravel package dont install illuminate/support

Tags: php, laravel-4

This happened when I tried installing the zizaco confide package.

This is how my composer.json looks after adding it:

http://pastebin.com/R9KgCaPR

I even reverted it back to where it was when it was working and still nothing:

http://pastebin.com/5hSvMs9E

And this is what command line gives me:

```
C:\Users\Halichu>H:

H:\>cd "H:\WD SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source\ATA\swafap"

H:\WD SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source\ATA\swafap>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0
    - Installation request for zizaco/confide 3.0.x -satisfiable by zizaco/con fide[3.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA3
    - zizaco/confide 3.0.0 requires illuminate/support 4.1.x -satisfiable by l aravel/framework[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.2,
v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1 .6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9],
illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1. 2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4,
v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, 4.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.1, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.2, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.3, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.4, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.5, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.6, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.7, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.8, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.9, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v4 .0.0-BETA2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.* -satisfiable by laravel /framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BETA2, v4.0.0-BETA3,
v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6,
v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].


H:\WD SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source\ATA\swafap>
```

I reviewed issues in Zizaco confide and this was an issue, but they supposedly fixed this about 2 days ago.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It also shows this error even when removing zizaco.. and it never did last week when I was running composer update..

Comment: Why you need `illuminate/support` separately, you have `Laravel's full stack`, remove `illuminate/support` and try.

Comment: Someone suggested adding it. I removed it.. still throws the error.

Comment: I even installed a new laravel, replaced the junky composer.json file with the new one, and it STILL throws the error.. how is this possible?..

Comment: Can you update `composer`, self update ?

Comment: It says could not open up input file : composer.phar

Comment: oh sorry `composer selfupdate` did update itself.. upgraded to a new version. but when i run composer update for laravel composer.json file, it still throws the same error

Comment: I even updated to laravel 4.1 : http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade

Comment: Just try to remove all packages and add one at a time for debugging and also try `"zizaco/confide": "dev-master"` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have this

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",  // <-- you have full stack in here
    "illuminate/support": "4.1.*", // <-- remove this line
    "teepluss/asset": "dev-master",
    "zizaco/confide": "3.0.x"
},
```

Remove `"illuminate/support": "4.1.*"` and `composer update` or if it doesn't help hen try to upgare to `Laravel`-`4.1*`. Follow [Upgrade Guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade).

Comment: how do you upgrade?... because that doesnt fix it. I even installed a new laravel, replaced the composer.json file with the new one and it still junks up..

Comment: Also try `"zizaco/confide": "dev-master"` instead.

Comment: Ok I followed this step by step : http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade and updated it. then i ran composer update and it still breaks..

Comment: Yes I updated composer and it worked just fine... I went back to the barebones of the composer.json file in laravel 4.1 and it still throw errors... when it wasn't before so i dont get it :/

Comment: Can you install a new `Laravel` project to make sure everything is fine.